# How to Limit MySQL query based on total records count percentage

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a query which returns a set of records where a condition is met. Then this I limit it randomly down to a number.

```
    SELECT
        word,
        quantity
    FROM
        Sentenses
    WHERE
        quantity = 1
    ORDER BY
        RAND()
    LIMIT 150
```

But I want the limit to be based on a percentage of total count of quantity field
is it possibile?

The current table it has 2000 records with criteria of quantity = 1 I get 350 random records which are limited to 150 per time. Instead of 150 limit I want this number to be based on percentage of 20%

thank you

Comment: can you explain with your table data architecture and desire result set ..

Comment: And how to treat random in this article??!?!